# How to find average in pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have Two Table in sql server 2008

```
   TABLE [tblTagDescription](
   [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [TopicID] [int] NULL,
   [TagID] [int] NULL,
   [FullTag] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [ValDecimal] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [ValBinary] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [GroupName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [ReportTag] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)

And

   TABLE [tblDataLog](
   [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [TagDescID] [bigint] NULL,
   [Value] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
   [Date] [datetime] NULL,
)
```

Here there might be same Group for multiple "Id" of tblDescription and "TagDescID" of tblDataLog.
Here 'Group1' has 10 ID as from 1 to 10. and there might be multiple record for these ID (from 1 to 10) in tbldatalog. I want these ID from 1 to as columns. I want Average of these ID (From 1 to 10). 
For this I used pivot:

```
 Declare @COls      nvarchar(max)
    Declare @SQL        nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @COlsID NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @COlsAlias NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MYTABLE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##MYTABLE
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tt') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tt

    IF(@Group='A')
    BEGIN
        Select @COls=COALESCE(@Cols + '],[','') + z.ReportTag From 
        (Select Distinct T.ID, ReportTag From tblTagDescription T
        Where isnull(ReportTag,'')<>'' AND T.GroupName=@Group Group BY T.ID,T.ReportTag --order by T.ID 
        )z  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
           @COlsID = @ColsID + ',' + z.TagDescID, 
           @COlsAlias = @COlsAlias + ',' + z.TagDescID + ' AS ' + z.ReportTag   
        FROM
            (select TagDescID,ReportTag from(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50 QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), 
            tblDataLog.TagDescID )) TagDescID,TagdescID TID, 
            QUOTENAME(tblTagDescription.ReportTag) ReportTag 
             FROM tblDataLog 
                INNER JOIN tblTagDescription ON tblDataLog.TagDescID = tblTagDescription.ID 
                where tblTagDescription.GroupName=@Group 
             ORDER BY  tblDataLog.TagDescID )s 
             ) z
    END

    SET @COlsID= STUFF(@COlsID,1,1,'')
    SET @COlsAlias= STUFF(@COlsAlias,1,1,'')

    SET @SQL='select [DATE],SHIFT, ' + @COlsAlias + ' into ##MYTABLE from ( select [Date], AVG(Value), TagDescID,
                 (CASE  
                            WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>6 and (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<14) THEN ''A'' 
                            WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>=14 and (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<22) THEN ''B'' 
                            WHEN ((DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))>=22 or (DATEPART(hour,[DATE]))<6) THEN ''C'' 
                        END )AS SHIFT 

                 from tblDataLog Group by [Date],[TagDescID] )d pivot(max(Value) for TagDescID in (' + @COlsID + ')) piv;'

        EXEC (@SQL)

        select * from ##MYTABLE
```

But the above query is giving error  as :

```
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'd'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'Value'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Select_DataViewer, Line 58
Invalid object name '##MYTABLE'.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: `PRINT` or `SELECT` the value of `@SQL`, debug that, and then propagate the solution to the code that creates the dynamic statement. Also [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)

Comment: You have not set an alias for 2nd column (`AVG(Value)`) in your dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why are you using a global temp table here? Seems like you could just skip the temp table entirely. Also you stated you are using sql server 2008...that is now an unsupported version. You should strongly consider upgrading to a newer supported version immediately if not sooner.

Comment: Actually i need to get average of all TagDescID of each hour of a given date range.